# Unable to Connect Using TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 Cipher Despite Being Listed in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, encryption, openssl, nginx-config, openssl-engine

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 server, running Openssl 1.1.1t, and nginx=1.21.6. I've configured `nginx.conf` to allow a set of ssl ciphers:

**nginx.conf**

```
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256';
```

- `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`
- `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`
- `ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305`
- `ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305`
- `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`
- `ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`
- `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM`
- `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM`
- `AES256-GCM-SHA384`
- `AES128-GCM-SHA256`
- `CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256`
- `TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256`
- `TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256`

According to the [official OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html), the ciphers `TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256` and `TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256` **are** supported.

However, when I try to connect to the target machine using the `openssl s_client` command, I get an error:

```
# openssl s_client -connect 192.168.2.15:443 -cipher TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 -tls1_3

Error with command: "-cipher TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256"
140594233390400:error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match:../ssl/ssl_lib.c:2564:
```

I tried to verify the supported ciphers using the `openssl ciphers -v` command, I do not see any matching ciphers:

```
#openssl ciphers -v | grep -i CCM
#
```

I am unable to track what actually I am missing here.

Comment: (0) this is not a programming or development issue, and is offtopic, but (1) OpenSSL by default _disables_ CCM suites, and the API used by `openssl ciphers XXX` _and_ by nginx `ssl_ciphers` ONLY sets/enables suites for TLS1.2 and below, ignoring any for TLS1.3. To see info, use `openssl ciphers -ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 -s -tls1_3`. To configure in nginx, use the workaround shown at [`ssl_conf_command`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_conf_command). Note you must use the full name(s); there are no abbreviations or groups for 1.3 suites.

Comment: I made changes on nginx.conf & sslscan shows

```
  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Preferred TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256        Curve P-521 DHE 521
Accepted  TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256      Curve P-521 DHE 521

```
When I try to connect to the target following error is seen

```
# openssl s_client -connect 192.168.2.15:443 -cipher TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 -tls1_3 
Error with command: "-cipher TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256"
140141519799616:error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match:../ssl/ssl_lib.c:2564:

```

Comment: `openssl s_client` has the same API issue as `openssl ciphers`; to specify a nondefault TLS1.3 suite you must use `-ciphersuites` instead. See [the man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-s_client.html#ciphersuites-val).